# How to close system Log from telephone

Tags: android

I'm learning android app development and here I find so many logs like below.

**I am sure the Logs are Not from my app, it is from wifi driver??**

**How can I close it?**

```java
01-17 22:45:43.007 8755-8952/? E/WifiConfigStore: has d0:c7:c0:11:09:e6 freq=2412 age=1640 ?=true
01-17 22:45:43.007 8755-8952/? E/WifiStateMachine: WifiStateMachine starting scan for "wifi"WPA_PSK with 2412
01-17 22:45:43.007 8755-8952/? E/WifiStateMachine: stopReconnectWifi Wfd=false StopScan=false mDontReconnectAndScan=false
01-17 22:45:43.008 8755-8952/? E/WifiStateMachine: [1,547,736,343,007 ms] noteScanstart no scan source uid -2
01-17 22:45:43.008 8755-18691/? E/WifiMonitor: handleEvent unknown: 15  CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
01-17 22:45:43.594 8755-8755/? E/WifiTrafficPoller: TRAFFIC_STATS_POLL true Token 1373 num clients 19
01-17 22:45:43.595 8755-8755/? E/WifiTrafficPoller:  packet count Tx=84893 Rx=71940
01-17 22:45:44.295 8755-8952/? E/WifiStateMachine:  ConnectedState (when=0 what=147461!SCAN_RESULTS_EVENT 0 0 found=17 known=1 got=17 bcn=0 con=1
01-17 22:45:44.295 8755-8952/? E/WifiStateMachine:  L2ConnectedState (when=-1ms what=147461!SCAN_RESULTS_EVENT 0 0 found=17 known=1 got=17 bcn=0 con=1
01-17 22:45:44.296 8755-8952/? E/WifiStateMachine:  ConnectModeState (when=-1ms what=147461!SCAN_RESULTS_EVENT 0 0 found=17 known=1 got=17 bcn=0 con=1
01-17 22:45:44.296 8755-8952/? E/WifiStateMachine:  DriverStartedState (when=-1ms what=147461!SCAN_RESULTS_EVENT 0 0 found=17 known=1 got=17 bcn=0 con=1
01-17 22:45:44.296 8755-8952/? E/WifiStateMachine:  SupplicantStartedState (when=-2ms what=147461!SCAN_RESULTS_EVENT 0 0 found=17 known=1 got=17 bcn=0 con=1
01-17 22:45:44.297 8755-8952/? E/WifiStateMachine: [1,547,736,344,297 ms] noteScanEnd no scan source onTime=0
01-17 22:45:44.304 8755-8952/? E/WifiStateMachine: wifi setScanResults statecom.android.server.wifi.WifiStateMachine$ConnectedState@fefd9d4 sup_state=COMPLETED debouncing=false mConnectionRequests=1 selection=<none>
01-17 22:45:44.305 8755-8952/? E/WifiConfigStore: updateSavedNetworkHistory(): try "wifi"WPA_PSK SSID="wifi" wifi [WPA-PSK-CCMP][WPA2-PSK-CCMP][WPS][ESS] ajst=0
01-17 22:45:44.305 8755-8952/? E/WifiConfigStore:         got known scan result d0:c7:c0:11:09:e6 key : "wifi"WPA_PSK num: 1 rssi=-53 freq=2412
01-17 22:45:44.307 8755-8952/? E/WifiAutoJoinController: status: bssid=d0:c7:c0:11:09:e6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Android Studio, in the **Logcat window** select "*Show only selected application*" for only viewing your application logs.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

These logs are from android system component for Wi-Fi, which uses these classes and prints their necessary logs. 
If you don't want to see it just go to **Logcat** window below and in the *right* corner, select **Show only selected application** from the dropdown menu. 
 
As a new android developer, I think you need to know something more about android **Log** class. Here is the official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat).